# Swift - Remove specific symbol from array

Tags: swift

Ive got an array thats created from JSON.
It looks something like this

```
let array = ["some-data", "more-data", "even-more-data", "data-again", "and-data"]
```

Whats the best way to remove the dashes.

I know theres a few ways to do this with a single string but is there a similar method I can use for an array?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
let withNoDa = array.map {$0.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "") }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks. Will accept the answer shortly.